# C# how to Download a file with a cookie(login)

Tags: c#, .net, networking, cookies, webrequest

I am trying to login on [this](https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/ucp.php?mode=login) website. Currently I'm using this code:

```
private string Login(string username, string password)
{
    string formUrl = "https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/ucp.php?mode=login";
    string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&affiliate-button=Sign%20In", username, password);
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Referer = formUrl;
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
#if DEBUG
    foreach (Cookie c in resp.Cookies)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(c.Name + " = " + c.Value);
#endif
    return resp.Headers["set-cookie"];
}
```

I always get 1 set-cookie back. When I login to this website with web browser(Chrome) I get back 10 + local storage. I have tried to use CookieCollection as follows:`resp.Cookies`. But i still got back only one cookie.

The other problem is, that i cant download [this](https://osu.ppy.sh/d/310339) file with the cookie I get. I only get back the login page.
For downloading i use this function:

```
private void Download(string url, string fileName, string cookies)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            req.Headers.Add(cookies);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Referer = "osu.ppy.sh";
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
            HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            using (Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                SaveToFile(respStream, fileName); //This reads the stream and writes to file
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

As I said before I used CookieCollection when I log in, I have also tried CookieContainer in this function like this:

```
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.CookieContainer.Add(cookies)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this to check if the cookie payload is comma separated -

```
    public void GetAllCookies(HttpWebRequest req, HttpWebResponse resp)
    {
        var cookies = resp.Headers["set-cookie"];

        foreach (var cookie in cookies.Split(','))
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(cookie, "(.+?)=(.+?);");
            if (match.Captures.Count == 0)
                continue;
            resp.Cookies.Add(
                new Cookie(
                    match.Groups[1].ToString(),
                    match.Groups[2].ToString(),
                    "/",
                    req.Host.Split(':')[0]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: there are not more cookies(i could already see that in debugger). But it makes 2 loops because there is ',' in expiration date: expires=Mon, 27-Jun-16 10:42:38 GMT;

Comment: In that case can you check the following as well ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975814/httpwebrequest-cookiecontainer

Comment: as I said there are no more cookies. This is the only one: `"__cfduid=d2f86d4ccbf88b2791b7b1db426d68c8f1435509938; expires=Mon, 27-Jun-16 16:45:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.ppy.sh; HttpOnly"`

Comment: and these are all the headers get in response: Transfer-Encoding, Connection, Pragma, CF-RAY, Content-Encoding, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Date, Expires, Set-Cookie, Server

Comment: I found out that i don't get the correct cookie back. Because if i pass in the Login function the incorrect password i get the same cookie(not the same value or expiration date, but everything else is the same).

Comment: Good to know that you figured it out !!

Comment: i didn't. i think that i'm passing the incorrect form parameters. should i pass the id=something or class=something (for username and password)?